# Is there any way to get dom path from inspector?

Tags: firefox

When there is an selected element from `inspector` tool, the bar (next to magnifying glass icon) will show the full DOM path.

[image]

Is there any helper to get that path without manually typing?

I try `R-Click` and `Ctrl-C` but nothing happened.

I want to use the path with Python's `beaytifulsoup`

**Expect** to have thing somewhat like this:

```
html>body>div#wrapper>article#main-content>h1.title-shadow-box
```

Comment: in chrome there is option to copy selector. 
right click on tag -> copy -> copy selector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Firefox 57. This is possible by right-clicking an element, **Copy** -> **CSS Path**.

[image: copy->csspath]

Alternatively, you can use the **CSS Selector** option to get a unique selector for that specific element.